# How to add russian language pack for ubuntu all applications?

Tags: 16.04

For example  `Gedit` doesn't show Russian symbols.  `sudo apt-get install language-pack-ru` doesn't solve this.

Comment: In  what files doesn't it show symbols?

Comment: .txt from WindowsMS, plain text document. Maybe just only for gedit, which command? Perhaps It needs to add UTF-8 coding, but how? Couldnt find any options.

Comment: You mean you can't type them or they are shown as gibberish?

Comment: Gibberish exactly!

Comment: What locale do you have configured (output of `locale`)? What's the character encoding of the text file (output of `file <FILENAME>`)? Could you include a link to it in your question, please? GEdit should be able to hand all perceivable encodings but it may not detect them reliably in your case.

Comment: What do you mean at "locale"? "a link to it" for the file? What for?  It has enought info for solving it i think. Russian language, all symbols on it. How could i change encoding mod in gedit? In bash please.